# Not Sure How to Write the Implicit for Equality Using Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

In Cats I can do

```scala
  import cats.Eq
  implicit val eq: Eq[Foo] = Eq.fromUniversalEquals[Foo]
```

How do I do this using Scalaz (7.3.1)? I tried this from the examples in the repo but I got a compile error:

```scala
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._
  implicit val eq: Equal[Foo] = Decidable[Equal].xderiving0(Foo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent universal equality representation in Scalaz would be:

```scala
    implicit val eq: Equal[Foo] = Equal.equalA[Foo]
```